# I want tot use the swagger APIs with angular 2 frontend. What will be the steps?

Tags: javascript, angular, swagger

I'm working on a angular 2 app and Now client wants me to use the APIs which are documented on swagger. Is there a module which I can import and just call the APIs from my angular 2 app? Or I need to install the swagger local and do all the calls from my local swagger installation.

Please advise, Bundle of Thanks in adnvace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenApi Descriptions (formerly called Swagger) are just descriptions of HTTP APIs.  You can call those APIs just like any other HTTP API.  No local tooling is required.  You could use a tool like [Swagger-codegen](https://swagger.io/swagger-codegen/) to generate a Typescript client but it is completely optional.